# Removing partial duplicate rows (duplicate data in only two columns) from Microsoft SQL Server 2012 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of around 7000 rows, a small sample of which is below:

```
ORG_ID     Entity_CLASS_ID     Entity_ID     ORGANISATION_ID     ORGANISATION_ROLE_ID    COLUMN_X
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
781        3                   998           896                 4                       1          
2098       3                   998           3191                4                       66   
3808       4                   998           3191                4                       6555     
780        3                   997           2402                4                       34234     
3807       4                   997           2061                4                       234    
2097       3                   997           2061                4                       6756
```

You will notice that for each Entity_ID, there are multiple rows. For each Entity_ID, there are two or more different `Entity_CLASS_ID`s.

You can see that in some circumstances two of the rows for each `Entity_ID` match on `ORGANISATION_ID` too, but have different `Entity_Class_ID`s:

```
ORG_ID     Entity_CLASS_ID     Entity_ID     ORGANISATION_ID     ORGANISATION_ROLE_ID    COLUMN_X     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2098       3                   998           3191                4                       66     
3808       4                   998           3191                4                       6555
```

Where this is the case i would like to delete the row with the entity class ID = 3.

The resulting tidied up table should be:

```
ORG_ID     Entity_CLASS_ID     Entity_ID     ORGANISATION_ID     ORGANISATION_ROLE_ID    COLUMN_X
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
781        3                   998           896                 4                       1          
3808       4                   998           3191                4                       6555     
780        3                   997           2402                4                       34234     
3807       4                   997           2061                4                       234
```

Hopefully I've explained that clearly!?

I've tried to work this out in code myself, but the mix of partial matches is stopping me from getting anywhere near a solution!

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using a CTE for this purpose:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity_ID, ORGANISATION_ID) cnt,
        MAX(Entity_CLASS_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY Entity_ID, ORGANISATION_ID) max_ecid
    FROM yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM cte
WHERE
    Entity_CLASS_ID = 3 AND   -- identifies the duplicate
    cnt = 2 AND               -- must occur in a pair
    max_ecid = 4;             -- the other record must be 4
```

Here is a running demo showing that the correct records are being identified for deletion:

[image: screen capture from demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using `exists`:

```
delete from t
where t.Entity_CLASS_ID = 3 and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.Entity_ID = t.Entity_ID and
                    t2.ORGANISATION_ID = t.ORGANISATION_ID and
                    t2.Entity_CLASS_ID <> 3
             );
```

This seems like almost a direct translation of your phrasing of the question.